# Can you compile an OCaml project natively as a windows library?

Tags: windows, dll, compiler-construction, ocaml, llvm

I am new to OCaml (but I have used SML in the past) and I want to know two things:
1- Can OCaml programs be compiled as libraries at all?
2- If so, can they be compiled as native Windows dlls.

What I want to do is create an compiler library in OCaml using LLVM and use it from another Windows program.

PS: I know I can use LLVM from C++ and C, but I prefer OCaml since I am doing it for fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see `ocamlopt` `-output-obj` option and chapter [18.7.5 Embedding the Caml code in the C code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual032.html#htoc249) of the manual.

Comment: Cool.By the way, what do I need to do to make a function callable from outside?

Comment: This is described in the same manual section : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual032.html#toc142

Comment: Link should now point to https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/native.html